# Try Catch and Setting return code

Tags: c#, try-catch, return-value

```
try
{
    // Write each directory name to a file.
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(textFileName))
    {
             foreach (DirectoryInfo view in generate.directories)
             {
                    sw.WriteLine(view.FullName);

             }
     }  

     using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(textFileName)) 
     {
           foreach (FileInfo view in generate.files)
           {
                 sw.WriteLine(view.FullName);

           }

      }

} 
catch(System.IO.IOException msg)
{
    code = 29;
    Console.WriteLine(msg.Message);
}

return code;
```

I have a method that writes the files/folders in a users directory to a text file. I used a try catch block to catch any write errors that might happen. Is it okay to set my return code within the catch block? Is it bad practice to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not bad practice, assuming you're checking the actual code in your other part of the code and then properly handling how the program reacts to `System.IO.IOException`.

Comment: I do indeed check the code, and handle how the program reacts. Many thanks.